# Distribute database records evenly across multiple processes

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a database table with 3 million records. A java thread reads 10,000 records from table and processes it. After processing it jumps to next 10,000 and so on. In order to speed up, i have 25 threads doing the same task (reading + processing), and then I have 4 physical servers running the same java program. So effectively i have 100 thread doing the same work (reading + processing).

I strategy i have used is to have a sql procedure which does the work of grabbing next 10,000 records and marking them as being processed by a particular thread. However, i have noticed that the threads seems to be waiting for a some time trying to invoke the procedure and getting a response back. What other strategy i can use to speed up this process of data selection.

My database server is mysql and programming language is java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way of handling such scenario is [producer-consumer](/questions/tagged/producer-consumer) design pattern. And in idiomatic way of implementing it in Java land is by using [jms](/questions/tagged/jms).

Essentially you need one master server reading records and pushing them to JMS queue. Then you'll have arbitrary number of consumers reading from that queue and competing with each other. It is up to you how you want to implement this in detail: do you want to send a message with whole record or only ID? All 10000 records in one message or record per message?

Another approach is [map-reduce](/questions/tagged/map-reduce), check out [hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop). But the learning curve is a bit steeper.

Comment: the only issue I can see with this method, is that the "write" queue will get jammed up.   The bottle neck is in the read/write cycle to the drive and I don't think there is anything he can do about that.

Comment: @Tomasz : with jms approach, what if the consumer dies for some reasons, then i have a set of messages which will not be processed, unless i put some kind of extra checking mechanism. With my current procedure approach, i'm able to bypass this scenario. If one server goes down, the rest will continue to work and pick up extra load.

Comment: @prashant: if you configure your consumers to be transactional, if the consumer fails to process some message (by dying, throwing an exception, whatever), the message broker will put this message back to the queue and another consumer will pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for Hadoop to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that you are majorly database IO bound with this scheme.  If you are trying to increase performance of your system, I would suggest partitioning your data across multiple database servers if you can do so.  [MySQL has some partitioning modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) that I have no experience with.  If you do partition yourself, it can add a lot of complexity to a database schema and you'd have to add some sort of routing layer using a hash mechanism to divide up your records across the multiple partitions somehow.  But I suspect you'd get a significant speed increase and your threads would not be waiting nearly as much.

If you cannot partition your data, then moving your database to a [SSD memory drive](http://www.mwave.com/mwave/subcat.asp?CatID=54&parent=2%5E49&pageTitle=Solid%20State%20Disks%20%28SSD%29) would be a huge win I suspect -- anything to increase the IO rates on those partitions.  Stay away from RAID5 because of the inherent performance issues.  If you need a reliable file system then mirroring or [RAID10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raid10#RAID_1.2B0) would have much better performance with [RAID50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raid10#RAID_50_.28RAID_5.2B0.29) also being an option for a large partition.

Lastly, you might find that your application performs better with less threads if you are thrashing your database IO bus.  This depends on a number of factors including concurrent queries, database layout, etc..  You might try dialing down the per-client thread count to see if that makes a different.  The effect may be minimal however.

Comment: Yup - if no SSD, get one now. Makes only a huge difference to large-file DB performance. For those apps, (like compilers/linkers), that generate a lot of small files, the difference is stupendous.

Comment: I would have gone to SSD first thing. But in large enterprise it's very hard to convince infrastructure and DBA team change the storage technology.